# Motorola Defy USB Debug Driver

Tags: 13.10, android, usb-drive, ubuntu-for-android

I am trying to connect a Motorola Defy(MB525) phone to my computer that is running Ubuntu 13.10. I can't connect my phone with my computer system successfully. What steps do I need to take for this to work?

Comment: post the link in which you are following?

Comment: How are u trying to connect? What errors do you get?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am not following any hint yet....

Comment: @Stormvirux I am connecting motorola defy with cable to my pc and trying to run android project on it from eclipse. As that time I am showing error unknown device. In short I can't able to debug my android project with motorola defy.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Thanks dude....I am getting success by selecting mass storage. :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj ya post it

Comment: @AvinashRaj : Ya please....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some Ubuntu versions by default, it won't support MTP mode.So you have to connect your phone in **Mass storage Mode** to view it's contents on Ubuntu PC.